# scala.MatchError: null on spark RDDs

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd, apache-spark-mllib, collaborative-filtering

I am relatively new to both spark and scala. 
I was trying to implement collaborative filtering using scala on spark.
Below is the code

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.recommendation.ALS
import org.apache.spark.mllib.recommendation.Rating

val data = sc.textFile("/user/amohammed/CB/input-cb.txt")

val distinctUsers = data.map(x => x.split(",")(0)).distinct().map(x => x.toInt)

val distinctKeywords = data.map(x => x.split(",")(1)).distinct().map(x => x.toInt)

val ratings = data.map(_.split(',') match {
  case Array(user, item, rate) => Rating(user.toInt,item.toInt, rate.toDouble)
})

val model = ALS.train(ratings, 1, 20, 0.01)

val keywords = distinctKeywords collect
  distinctUsers.map(x => {(x, keywords.map(y => model.predict(x,y)))}).collect()
```

It throws a **scala.MatchError: null
        org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.lookup(PairRDDFunctions.scala:571)** at the last line
Thw code works fine if I collect the distinctUsers rdd into an array and execute the same code:

```
val users = distinctUsers collect
  users.map(x => {(x, keywords.map(y => model.predict(x, y)))})
```

Where am I getting it wrong when dealing with RDDs?

Spark Version : 1.0.0 
Scala Version : 2.10.4

Comment: I'm not sure, but try to put `keywords` in a [broadcast variable](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#broadcast-variables) before the last line. (I'm never sure when something gets automatically captured and when you need to broadcast...)

Comment: That was a good idea. It never crossed my mind. Thanks for the idea but the error remains. I have also tried broadcasting variable `model`.

Comment: what is your spark version number?

Comment: Apologies I did not mention it in the question. Spark : 1.0.0. Scala : 2.10.4

Comment: Just a note: usually `x => {(x, keywords.map(y => model.predict(x,y)))}` would be written more like `{ x => (x, keywords.map { y => model.predict(x, y) }) }`. `{}` is used to define a block, which returns its last statement as its value. As you may have noticed, `_` can be used to match arguments by position, as in `List(1, 2, 3).map(_ * 2).reduce(_ + _)`, but for clarity or to use an argument twice, you should give it a name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going one call further back in the stack trace, line 43 of the [MatrixFactorizationModel](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/mllib/recommendation/MatrixFactorizationModel.scala#L43) source says:

```
val userVector = new DoubleMatrix(userFeatures.lookup(user).head)
```

Note that the `userFeatures` field of `model` is itself another RDD; I believe it isn't getting serialized properly when the anonymous function block closes over `model`, and thus the `lookup` method on it is failing. I also tried placing both `model` and `keywords` into broadcast variables, but that didn't work either.

Instead of falling back to Scala collections and losing the benefits of Spark, it's probably better to stick with RDDs and take advantage of other ways of transforming them.

I'd start with this:

```
val ratings = data.map(_.split(',') match {
  case Array(user, keyword, rate) => Rating(user.toInt, keyword.toInt, rate.toDouble)
})

// instead of parsing the original RDD's strings three separate times,
// you can map the "user" and "product" fields of the Rating case class

val distinctUsers = ratings.map(_.user).distinct()
val distinctKeywords = ratings.map(_.product).distinct()

val model = ALS.train(ratings, 1, 20, 0.01)
```

Then, instead of calculating each prediction one by one, we can obtain the Cartesian product of all possible user-keyword pairs as an RDD and use the other `predict` method in MatrixFactorizationModel, which takes an RDD of such pairs as its argument.

```
val userKeywords = distinctUsers.cartesian(distinctKeywords)

val predictions = model.predict(userKeywords).map { case Rating(user, keyword, rate) =>
  (user, Map(keyword -> rate))
}.reduceByKey { _ ++ _ }
```

Now `predictions` has an immutable map for each user that can be queried for the predicted rating of a particular keyword. If you specifically want arrays as in your original example, you can do:

```
val keywords = distinctKeywords.collect() // add .sorted if you want them in order
val predictionArrays = predictions.mapValues(keywords.map(_))
```

*Caveat: I tested this with Spark 1.0.1 as it's what I had installed, but it should work with 1.0.0 as well.*

Comment: Thanks this is what I was looking for. I wanted to know some links or books to learn Spark and Scala.

Comment: The Spark docs are improving all the time -- I hadn't used MLlib's collaborative filtering before, but the [example](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-collaborative-filtering.html) you might have seen helped me to work with it. For dealing with Scala in general, you might try Twitter's [Scala School](https://twitter.github.io/scala_school/) which gives a quick overview of many useful features of the language.